# How to give multiple conditions in join in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am doing it as given below but it is throwing `error: 2S22 - 1054 - Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'`.

`->join('kyc_freetext','kyc_freetext.kyc_id=kyc_detail.id and kyc_freetext.relivance=1',array('freetext_value'),'left')`

What to do?

Comment: In this case you should use where method

Answer (score 1):

You can use new Expression command in join condition

```
new Expression('jobs.id = app.jobId AND app.applyStatus = 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the join string being quoted you can use an expression, this will work:

```
->join('kyc_freetext',new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('kyc_freetext.kyc_id=kyc_detail.id and kyc_freetext.relivance=1'),array('freetext_value'),'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

->join('kyc_freetext',new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('kyc_freetext.kyc_id = kyc_detail.id and kyc_freetext.relivance = 1'), ['freetext_value'], \Zend\Db\Sql\Select::JOIN_LEFT);